# Check whether the file is existing in a specific folder on - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have an arrayformula that simulates an image path in the entire column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(A:A)=1,"@icon",IF(A:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(LOWER("../Icons/"&A:A&".png"), " ", "_"))))
```

Which outputs for example: `../Icons/example.png`

Next up, I would like to give the cell a background-color if the image can/can't be found in that relative path. The Google Sheet and images are all saved at Google Drive. Is this even possible to achieve or do I have to change my setup in order to get to know somehow if that image location can be found?

#### Example (conditional format?)

[image: Example]

Comment: this does not make any sense. is this related to google disk folder or some website? there needs to be some link between something and your google sheet and based on that you can have conditional formatting

Comment: @player0 Thanks for pionting that out and my bad for being a bit unclear. It is related to the Google Drive Disk. Conditional logic seems the way to go, but I’m not sure if this is even possible in the first place? Loading in the image in a cell with a working formula is a good alternative as well if that’s even an option.

Comment: Can I ask you about `relative path` you think and `../Icons/example.png`? 1. In order to check whether the file is existing in the specific folder, it is required to use Google Apps Script. How about this? 2. What is `relative path` the path for? 3. When `example.png` of `../Icons/example.png` is checked whether the file is existing, where is the folder of `../Icons`? 4. For example, in Google Drive, when the folder name of `Icon` is only one in your Google Drive, the script will be a simple. How about this?